# Customizing plot DPI in markdown presentation

Tags: r, knitr, xaringan

I'm struggling to control the size and DPI of the images in my markdown presentation.  I'm using the `xaringan` package.

The chunk options for fig.width and fig.height work intuitively until I change the dpi setting.  For higher dpi settings, I can't seem to produce an image with appropriate size and appearance.  Increasing dpi makes the image huge; I can compensate by decreasing fig.height and fig.width, but that ruins the scaling of the plot area and font sizes.  Any help is appreciated!

I included some code, but I put it all in comments because otherwise StackOverflow will get confused about formatting the chunk options.

````r
# ---
# title: Test plot appearance
# output:
#   xaringan::moon_reader:
#       css: [chocolate-fonts]
#       lib_dir: libs
#       nature:
#       highlightStyle: github
#       countIncrementalSlides: false
# ---
# 
# ```{r include = FALSE}
# library(ggplot2)
# ```
# 
# # Default DPI is low res
# ```{r echo = FALSE, fig.width = 6, fig.height = 4}
# ggplot(mtcars) + aes(cyl, mpg) + geom_point()
# ```
# 
# ---
# # 300 DPI makes image huge
# ```{r echo = FALSE, fig.width = 6, fig.height = 4, dpi = 300}
# ggplot(mtcars) + aes(cyl, mpg) + geom_point()
# ```
# 
# ---
# # I can compensate with small fig.width and height, but looks ugly
# ```{r echo = FALSE, fig.width = 2, fig.height = 2, dpi = 300}
# ggplot(mtcars) + aes(cyl, mpg) + geom_point()
# ```
# 
# ---
# # out.width and out.height cause image not to appear
# ```{r echo = FALSE, out.width = 6, out.height = 4, dpi = 300}
# ggplot(mtcars) + aes(cyl, mpg) + geom_point()
# ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I think what you may want is the `fig.retina` chunk option.

E.g., when `fig.retina = 2`, the physical size of an image is doubled and its display size is halved.

In terms of `out.width` or `out.height`, the input needs to be character. If you want to use this option, you may like to use it like `out.width = "80%"`.

See more plot options [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots).